# Custom keymap not available in Gnome Input sources

Tags: keyboard, gnome, keyboard-layout

I've created a custom keymap based on Bepo (a french dvorak-like), which is working correctly when I set it using

```
setxkbmap fr bepo_prog
```

However, this keyboard mapping is not visible in Gnome input sources selector. It wouldn't be a problem if I used my bepo keyboard everytime, but it is a laptop so sometimes I go back to azerty. It is especially problematic when I want to unlock the computer, since the keymap set by **setxkbmap** takes priority over Gnome shell layout selector (i.e. layout selector does not work anymore), and it can be extremely painful to put the password (which is really long) to unlock the session (I just started learning bepo so it can be hard to type for now without looking at the keyboard).

Is there anyway for Gnome to see this custom layout?

I'm on a Fedora 21, with Gnome 3.14.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Debian with Gnome 3.14.1.  For my custom keyboard layout, I got Gnome to recognize it by adding the details to /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml.

The layout "fr" is already in that file on my system, but the variant "bepo_prog" isn't.  If yours is the same, the best way is probably to search through evdev.xml for the string "bepo" and duplicate it's variant section, so you'd probably add something like this to the file:

```
<variant>
  <configItem>
    <name>bepo_prog</name>
    <description>French (Bepo, ergonomic, Prog)</description>
  </configItem>
</variant>
```

If that doesn't work in Fedora, you might try following the more detailed [guide at the X.org site](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Enhancing.html).